# data type conversion between R and java

Tags: java, r

guys
I want to call java in R,so the most import thing is that how to convert data type between R and java,I knew '.jnew'  'new' can create a java object,however ,after I called java function,how can I convert the returns values to R data type

```
j_d2 = .jnew("java.util.Date",'2011-1-1')
```

for the example,how can I convert j_d2 to POSIXCT type in R
appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R doesn't know how to convert Java objects other the primitives mapped through JNI (when using .jcall). You will need to provide your own conversion e.g. by parsing string representation of your date project using as.POSIXct(j_d2$toString, format="..."). See ?strptime for the format specification.

For example, in my locale I use the following format:

```
> library(rJava)
> .jinit()

> j_d2 <- str(.jnew("java/util/Date"))
> j_d2$toLocaleString()
[1] "8-Dec-2013 9:05:00 PM"
> as.POSIXct(j_d2$toLocaleString(), format="%e-%b-%Y %X %p")
[1] "2013-12-08 09:05:00 PST"
```

The string conversion is inefficient if you need to convert a lot of dates. Alternatively you may use this [method](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.rosuda.devel/1328) described by Simon Urbanek:

```
> d <- .jnew("java/util/Date","2013/12/08 08:00")
> d
[1] "Java-Object{Sun Dec 08 08:00:00 PST 2013}"

> # Java uses milliseconds, R expects seconds
> as.POSIXct(.jcall(d,"J","getTime")/1000, origin = "1960-01-01")
[1] "2003-12-08 08:00:00 PST"
```